# Filtering an array and then mapping it isn't displaying results with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  let [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [newCountry, newStuff] = useState("");
  const hook = () => {
    //console.log("effect");
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      console.log("promise fulfilled");
      setCountries(response.data);
      //console.log(response.data);
    });
  };

  const filter = (event) => {
    newStuff(event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === undefined) {
      return
    } else {
      let value = event.target.value;
      console.log(value);
      countries = countries.filter((country) => country.name.startsWith(value));
      setCountries(countries);
      console.log(countries);
    }
  };
  useEffect(hook, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>find countries</p>
      <input value={newCountry} onChange={filter} />
      <ul>
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <li key={country.name.length}>{country.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

So I have a search bar so that when you enter a few characters it will update the state and show the countries that start with the respective first characters. However, nothing is being shown when I enter input into my search bar. Also, my filter function, when I console.log my countries array which is supposed to have the countries that start with the characters I entered, it's always an empty array.

Comment: You need to wrap your `hook` into async `useCallback`. And you are not able to mutate state `countries`. Use immutable way to update your state.

Comment: Do I just need to put await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in order to make this work:

1. Use two states for countries, one for the list you
   get in the initial render and another for the current filter
   countries.

   ```
   const [countriesStore, setCountriesStore] = useState([]); // this only change in the first render
   const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]); // use this to print the list
   ```

   I recomed to use any tool to manage the state and create a model for
   the countries ther you can make the side effect there and create an
   action that update the countries store. I'm using [Easy Peasy](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/) in
   my current project and it goes very well.
2. Take care of the filter method because startsWith
   method is not case-insensitive. You need a regular expression or
   turn the current country value to lower case. I recommend to use
   includes method to match seconds names like island in the search.

   ```
   const filterCountries = countriesStore.filter(country => {
         return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(value);
    });
   ```
3. Remove the if condition in the filter in order to include the
   delete action in the search and get the full list again if
   everything is removed.
4. Just in the case, empty the search string state in the first
   render

   useEffect(() => {
   hook();
   setSearchString("");
   }, []);
5. Replace the length in the list key. You can use the name and trim to remove space.

   `<li key={country.name.trim()}>{country.name}</li>`

The final code look like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [countriesStore, setCountriesStore] = useState([]);
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");

  const hook = () => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
      console.log("promise fulfilled");
      setCountriesStore(response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  };

  const filter = event => {
    setSearchString(event.target.value);

    let value = event.target.value;

    const filterCountries = countriesStore.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(value);
    });

    setCountries(filterCountries);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    hook();
    setSearchString("");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>find countries</p>
      <input value={searchString} onChange={filter} />
      <ul>
        {countries.map(country => (
          <li key={country.name.trim()}>{country.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your hook into async useCallback:

```
const hook = useCallback(async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");
    setCountries(data);
}, []);
```

you are not able to mutate state countries. Use immutable way to update your state:

```
const filter = (event) => {
    newStuff(event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === undefined) {
      return
    } else {
      let value = event.target.value;
      setCountries(countries.filter((country) => country.name.startsWith(value)));
    }
};
```

And `useState` is asynchronous function. You will not see result immediately. Just try to console.log outside of any function.

Comment: So when would I see the result? I console.log outside of filter function but my array still has nothing